# ¿Cómo simular el pulsado de una tecla en C++?

Tags: c++, script, autocompletar

Estoy intentando crear un script para auto logearme en una aplicación de escritorio. El problema es que después de iniciar la aplicación con

```
system("C:\carpeta\miprograma.exe")
```

No sé como insertar en el cuadro de texto de la aplicación el usuario y posteriormente hacer <kbd>TAB</kbd> insertar el password y <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Al abrir el programa el cursor se sitúa automáticamente en el cuadro de texto  donde se inserta el usuario, no obstante no conozco ninguna función que permita enviar una cadena a la posición del cursor.

Comment: ¿Has probado con [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)? Te permite crear scripts que hacen lo que pides y generar un ejecutable. También puedes usar el [API de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) para generar eso mismo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, se que con AutoIT sería más fácil, pero me gustaría saber si es posible en c++.

Comment: Mira el enlace que te pasé con este mensaje: [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove). Aquí tienes el listado de otros [mensajes de interés](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input-notifications).

Comment: Esto no es un problema específico de C++. Lo que tienes que hacer es hablar con la API de Windows (y ahí el lenguaje utilizado es prácticamente irrelevante). El comentario de @OscarGarcia puede ser un buen punto de entrada

Comment: Perdón, me he centrado en mensajes del ratón porque pensé que era lo que necesitabas. Hay una llamada al API específica para [enviar pulsaciones de teclas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). Prueba a usar el API y si te sigue fallando o sigue sin funcionar pregúntanos algo más concreto y te ayudaremos a corregir el código o a hacerlo correctamente. ¡Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido resolver el problema, adjunto el código por si a alguien le interesa en un futuro

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string user = "micorreo@root";
    string password = "mipassword";

    vector<INPUT>   userVector;
    vector<INPUT>   passwordVector;
    vector<INPUT>   tabulador;
    vector<INPUT>   enter;
    INPUT input;


    //vector para el "TAB"
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wVk = 0x9;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0x0;
    tabulador.push_back(input);

    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    tabulador.push_back(input);

    //vector para el "ENTER"
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0x0;
    enter.push_back(input);

    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    enter.push_back(input);

    //vector para el usuario
    for (auto caracter : user)
    {
        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.wVk = 0;
        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        input.ki.wScan = caracter;
        userVector.push_back(input);

        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        userVector.push_back(input);
    }

    //vector para la password
    for (auto caracter : password)
    {
        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.wVk = 0;
        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        input.ki.wScan = caracter;
        passwordVector.push_back(input);

        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        passwordVector.push_back(input);
    }


    //Abrimos la aplicacion en la que nos logearemos
    system("start C:\\Users\\Aplicaciondelogin.exe");
    Sleep(1800);  //Esperamos a que el programa carge

    HWND hwnd = FindWindow("Aplicaciondelogin.exe", 0);
    if (hwnd)
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    else
        std::cout << "no se encuentra el programa!\n";


    //Enviamos las teclas
    SendInput(userVector.size(), userVector.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
    SendInput(tabulador.size(), tabulador.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
    SendInput(passwordVector.size(), passwordVector.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
    SendInput(enter.size(), enter.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
    return 0;
}
```

agradecimientos a @OscarGarcia